# Getting days count from start day and number of day for a group of days in Java 8

Tags: java

I have a List of Objects containing following structure

```
public class DaySpan{
 private LocalDate date;
 private Integer numberOfDays;
..
..
//getters & setters
}
```

Lets say the list contains 3 instances of above classes with data (date is in dd/mm/yyyy)

- 04/02/2020 3
- 03/02/2020 5
- 01/02/2020 1

Then I need ouput for count of each day that is getting overlapped in number of days
For example the first record will translate to 04/02/2020, 05/02/2020, 06/02/2020
Second record will translate to 03/02/2020, 04/02/2020, 05/02/2020, 06/02/2020, 07/02/2019 and the final record will translate to 01/02/2020
So the output will be

- 01/02/2020 - 1
- 03/02/2020 - 1
- 04/02/2020 - 2
- 05/02/2020 - 2
- 06/02/2020 - 2
- 07/02/2020 - 1

The code I have written is

```
   public void getDayCount(List<DaySpan> daySpans){

    Map<Object, Long> days = new HashMap();
    days = daySpans.stream()
            .map(this::getDays)
            .collect(
                Collector.of(ArrayList::new, 
                    List::addAll,(left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }
                    )
                )
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    days.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
  }


  public List<LocalDate> getDays(DaySpan daySpan) {
    return Stream.iterate(daySpan.getStartDate(), d -> d.plusDays(1)).limit(daySpan.getNumberOfDays())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You came far to a good solution.

```
public void getDayCount(List<DaySpan> daySpans){
    Map<LocalDate, Long> freqs = daySpans.stream()
            .flatMap(daySpan ->
                IntStream.range(0, daySpan.numberOfDays)
                    .mapToObj(i -> daySpan.date.plusDays(i)))
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    freqs.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

- Creating a `Stream<LocalDate>` for some DaySpan is simply realized by an `IntStream.range`.
- A flatMap makes a larger Stream of LocalDates.
- Turning them into a counting map you already did.
- Sorting them on the date remains.
- You printed the entries as Entry, so I kept it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use flatMap to convert a stream of streams into a single stream, which achieves your goal of accumulating the results of all the getDays calls into one collection:

```
public void getDayCount(List<DaySpan> daySpans) {
    Map<Object, Long> days = daySpans.stream()
            .map(this::getDays)
            .flatMap(o -> o.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    days.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```